# Does min-norm least squares solve regular least squares in some basis?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

For a data matrix $X$ of dimension $n \times p$ where $p > n$ and corresponding label vector $y$ of dimension $n$, the standard least squares fit, $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, is underdetermined. A typical approach is to use the Moore-Penrose inverse to find the min-norm solution by solving $\hat{\beta}^{\text{mn}} = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}y$. Specifically, this finds $\min_\hat{\beta} ||\hat{\beta}||^2_2$ such that $X \hat{\beta} = y$.

My question is if the min-norm solution described above for a data matrix $X$ is equivalent to solving standard least squares for some $n \times n$ basis of $X$? In other words, if we call this basis $B$ could we solve $\hat{\beta}^{\text{basis}} = B^T(BB^T)^{-1}y$ such that $\hat{\beta}^{\text{basis}}$ and $\hat{\beta}^{\text{mn}}$ are equivalent even for a test point not in $X$?